# Apply a Picture Texture

Tags: texturing

I'm making a quasi-3d model for Sanic the Hegehog where it's just a cut out of an image that was given depth. However, I'm trying to put the same image as the texture, but it's shrunk down and tiled. How could I blow up the image so that way it fits out the cutout[image: Here be a pic of Sanic]

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your cutout model is already extruded.

Select the outline of your cutout and mark seams for unwrap.

Select all the front faces and unwrap them (Project from View is best in this case). 
Load your sonic picture in uv window and adjust the resize the unwrap (if the picture is in box size like 400x400, 512x512, it's going to fit perfect)

After this, in 3d view, Press Ctrl+I to invert the selection and unwrap it too. In Uv Window, press w and select weld (This turns the other selected faces into 1 single dot) and place the result where ever you seem appropriate.

Give material to your model and add the sonic texture sheet.

Comment: Its sanic not sonic :P